# how to test IQueryable of strongly typed using xUnit in .NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, xunit, nsubstitute, autofixture

I am working on a test project for .NET CORE Web API project. I have SchoolService class that implements numbers of methods as some of them below

### Service Class

```
 public class SchoolService : ISchoolService
{
    private readonly ISchoolEntity schoolEntity;

    public SchoolService(ISchoolEntity schoolEntity)
    {
        this.schoolEntity = schoolEntity;
    }


    public IQueryable<SchoolDataView> GetAllSchools()
    {
        var query = this.schoolEntity.GetAllSchool();
        return query;
    }

    public SchoolDataView GetSchoolById(Guid Id)
    {
        var query = this.schoolEntity.GetSchoolById(Id);
        return query;
    }
```

I want to test
1- GetAllSchools return object type is of IQueryable?
2- How I use autofix or by another way for schoolEntity.GetAllSchool() return fake IQueryable?

### Service Test

```
 public class SchoolServiceTests
{
    private readonly ISchoolService schoolService;
    private readonly ISchoolEntity schoolEntity = Substitute.For<ISchoolEntity>();

    public SchoolServiceTests()
    {
        schoolService = new SchoolService(schoolEntity);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetAllSchool_ShouldReturn_IQueryableOfSchoolDataView()
    {
        //Arrange


        //Act
        var a = schoolEntity.GetAllSchool();

        //Assert
        Assert.??
    }
}
```

Comment: Is you target to test the service implementation (SchoolService)? Then why do you execute GetAllSchool in ISchoolEntity? What is your expectation here you are calling a fake method which always will return an IQueryable. Just as a hint from my experience: I am always using the Moq framework where you can mock all your interface implementations very easy.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I have answered my question, It gives me an answer but wants your feedback and suggestion as my Subject under test is SchoolService Method so is this right way to do?

Comment: Probably I don't understand, but why do you want to test that return type of `GetAllSchool` is `IQueryable<SchoolDataView>` if this is already sort of tested by the compiler?

Comment: I think it would make some sense if the return type was like `object`, but in your case everything is quite clear, you can only return objects of types which implement `IQueryable< SchoolDataView >`. What's the reason to write test for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have written following test to achieve behaviour that I have stated in my question. Open to hearing more feedback and suggestions on it. Thanks

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetAllSchool_ShouldReturn_IQueryableOfSchoolDataView()
    {
        //Arrange
  
        var schoolDataViewList = new List<SchoolDataView>
        {
            new SchoolDataView { SchoolID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "London Primary School"},
            new SchoolDataView { SchoolID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Windsor Gramer School"},
            new SchoolDataView { SchoolID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Kings College"},
            new SchoolDataView { SchoolID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Reading School"}
        }.AsQueryable();

        schoolEntity.GetAllSchool().Returns(schoolDataViewList);

        //Act
        var actualSchoolList = sut.GetAllSchools();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IQueryable<SchoolDataView>>(actualSchoolList);
    }
```

### OR Using AutoFixture

```
 [Fact]
    public void GetAllSchool_ShouldReturn_IQueryableOfSchoolDataView()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();

        var schoolDataViewMock = fixture.CreateMany<SchoolDataView>();
       
        schoolEntity.GetAllSchool().Returns(schoolDataViewMock.AsQueryable());

        //Act
        var actualSchoolDataList = sut.GetAllSchools();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IQueryable<SchoolDataView>>(actualSchoolDataList);
    }
```

Comment: I like feedback on the above approaches please

Comment: When your test is going to fail (I mean red line, not compilation error)? For me it seems that never, probably only when `actualSchoolDataList` is `null`, but in that case I would test the result against `null` rather than return type.